# Azure Service Fabric Health monitoring of applications written in Node.js through REST

Tags: node.js, azure-service-fabric, health-monitoring

I found a quote from Microsoft here:

> Once the health reporting design is clear, health reports can be sent
>   easily. You can use FabricClient to report health if the cluster is
>   not secure or if the fabric client has admin privileges. This can be
>   done through the API by using FabricClient.HealthManager.ReportHealth,
>   through PowerShell, or through REST.

I am pretty much interested in health monitoring through REST client since I'm developing Node.js application. Has anyone heard anything about this and can point me to the health monitoring REST Api specs/examples/anything?

Answer (score 1):

Since I got the answer from Microsoft I will share it for others to leverage.

There is indeed a REST API:

- [Service Reporting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn707653.aspx)
- [Replica Reporting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn707685.aspx)